# What is causing high-pitch noise over Bluetooth signal.

Tags: bluetooth, audio, interference

My question is similar to this:

[Bluetooth Interference with High Pitched Tone](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/142091/bluetooth-interference-with-high-pitched-tone?newreg=b350c5b8ef8144b9a9d6e2cc372e3f4e)

I am hearing a high-pitch noise from my Windows 7 laptop when using bluetooth headphones. I only hear this when connected to my laptop, other devices don't cause this.  I've updated drivers on my laptop and worked with settings, but nothing has helped.

The high-pitch noise is either there or it isn't. I've noticed that sometimes the noise isn't present, typically after a restart. Maybe this is because there is a process that runs at some point which causes the issue.

Could someone help me outline what the potential reasons are which may cause this? From a simplistic understanding, the fact that I have static over a digital signal when listening to an mp3 from my laptop must mean that my laptop is not sending me a stream of the mp3, but some consolidated audio signal created by some process on the OS.

1. Could there be a physical reason that is causing the high-pitch?
2. Is there potentially some other audio source that is being mixed in?

I was hoping that someone might be able to help me outline a plan of attack to solve the problem.

What I've done so far:

1. Updated LT bluetooth drivers
2. Updated integrated soundcard drivers.
3. Disabled all other sound devices, including microphones.
4. Disabled all Bluetooth input settings for the headphones.

Comment: Do you get the same or similar extraneous tones when using USB or TRS-connector headphones?

Comment: Also, I would guess that you answer your question: Yes, the reason is most likely physical. It is due to the design of the audio components on the laptop. And there is very likely nothing or next to nothing you can do if you want to keep using Bluetooth as your transmission method. Moving the audio processor off of the laptop would remove the audio processing from the source of the extraneous tones, but that requires a USB-based audio device, and therefore a physical cable.

Comment: It isn't clear to me: is the noise being emitted by the headphone speakers as part of the audio signal; from some place on the headphones not part of the speakers; from some internal source in the laptop; other?

Comment: Does it by chance happen more often when you are receiving notifications, texts or phone calls?

Comment: @ConstantFun It doesn't seem to be impacted by what my phone is doing. Maybe there is a frequency overlap, but I only hear it when listening to my laptop. All other devices don't cause this issue. See my answer for how I addressed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've dealt with this issue for a while and found a way to "solve" the problem.

To recap the issue, I hear static/buzzing when I am listening to sound on my laptop via any bluetooth device.

My solution was to max the volume output on my laptop, and use my bluetooth device to decide the listening volume. It doesn't completely eliminate the problem, but at least it decreases the static/buzzing to a tolerable level.

Answer (score 2):

So something super simple to check is 1) has your power plug/ extension cord come loose from the wall socket??? and 2) move your computer power supply FROM an extension cord TO a direct wall socket.....  seems simple but man it was the only fix that worked for my bluetooth headset!!